# Awk command file: How to accomplish this task

Tags: linux, bash, awk

In awk there is `toupper()` to capitalize text and `gsub()` to replace text

I have seen examples of how to do each task on a file, and they work, however I am curious as to how to make a command file that when piplined with "who" will accomplish the following:

Instead of "who" outputting like such:

```
firstname.lastname pts/# .....[other information]
```

It will output like this:

```
Firstname, Lastname TTY #     [other information removed]
```

How can this task be accomplished in an awk command file please?

Comment: What environment are you working in? I've never seen who output firstname.lastname ...

Comment: When "uname -r" is entered into the command line, the output is:

3.11.10-29-desktop, it is linux

Comment: OK, my apologies, my question wasn't very specific. What I wanted to know is how your users authenticate, where user information for your hosts is stored/retrieved from.

Comment: Ah I am afraid it is not my server xD Just the uni's one that we connect to, unsure of that information =/

Comment: And the string TTY in the desired output, is that static?

Comment: Ah yes it will just be TTY for every line of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a cleaner way but this is my attempt.

```
echo "firstname.lastname pts/# .....[other information]" |
awk  'r=gensub(/([[:alnum:]]*)\.([[:alnum:]]*).*/, "\\1 \\2", "",$1),
split(r,a," ")
{ print toupper(substr(a[1],1,1)) substr(a[1], 2) " " toupper(substr(a[2],1,1)) substr(a[2], 2) " TTY#" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

for any field you can do this

```
awk '{print toupper(substr($1,1,1)) tolower(substr($1,2,length($1)-1))'
```

I'm not familiar with the firstname.lastname who format (I see userid instead).

Comment: The output of `who` depends entirely on the system-auth. In one of our production environment, we use radius to authenticate. The `userid` is in `firstname.lastname` format. In short, it is the userid :)